# Do I need to use random.seed() with random.uniform() to ensure I get different sequences

Tags: python

Do I have to use random.seed() to ensure random numbers are different OR random.uniform already sets a new seed every time that is called?
I do not want to repeat sequences so does it matter if I use seed at all?

Comment: A reason for using a seed is so that the results are reproducible.  For actual and non-reproducible randomness (instead of pseudo-randomness) use random.SystemRandom (https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom). It can generate values of a uniform distribution, for example random.SystemRandom().uniform(0,1000000)

Comment: You have the logic reversed, you only call seed to get deterministic values returned

Comment: Random.uniform() returns a new random number from a PRNG sequence. When that PRNG is seeded with the same value it produces the same sequence. Random is seeded with current system time on module import by default. You only need to seed explicitly to enable reproduction of the same sequence which can be important for simulations.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: pseudo-randomness is not random and can be predicted even if the seed is random, by spectral analysis, etc. That's not true for random.SystemRandom, supposedly.

Comment: @TrisNefzger, yes you could use `os.urandom` but how secure that is also depends on your OS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Case 1:

```
import random
random.seed(10)

for i in range(3):
    print random.randrange(2000)
```

### Output of Case 1:

```
$ python b.py
1142
857
1156
$ python b.py
1142
857
1156
```

As you see, in case 1, the different sessions (running the program is a session) produce the same set of random variables.

### Case 2:

```
import random

for i in range(3):
    print random.randrange(2000)
```

### Output of Case 2:

```
$ python b.py
1469
1559
267
$ python b.py
1252
476
1804
```

In case 2, on the other hand, the set of random variables in different sessions are also different.

This is because when you import random, it *randomly* picks a seed. And the seeds are likely to be different in different sessions.

However, if you override the seed, then you will have the same set of random variables, as we see in case 1.